# <select id="FooterList2" asp-items="@(new SelectList( ViewBag.FooterList2,"Id","Title"))" class="form-control col-md-5"></select>

Tags: asp.net, footer

In the section on dynamic constants in the footer section, when a title is entered, the previous titles are not deleted and the newly entered title is added to the previous titles. What should be done to solve this problem?

Comment: Please reply if you know

Comment: Your question is not clear, do not write your code on the question subject, post your code with describing your issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.